# How to combine cdkVirtualScroll with cdkTable?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I'm looking for a working virtual scroll table with fixed headers, so I found the Cdk which is great but the documentation is really difficult to follow. At the moment I'm trying to combine the `CdkTable` with `CdkVirtualScoll`.

All working examples I could found are using Material table, but I don't.

So how can I get `CdkVirtualScoll` get to work? Here is what I have done so far (from the examples):

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
<cdk-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="username">
        <cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> User name </cdk-header-cell>
        <cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.username}} </cdk-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="title">
        <cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Title </cdk-header-cell>
        <cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.title}} </cdk-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Header and Row Declarations -->
    <cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="['username', 'age']"></cdk-header-row>
    <cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: ['username', 'age']"></cdk-row>
</cdk-table>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

As in the documentation is written, the table was wrapped into the scrolling viewport. But how and where can I set the `*cdkVirtualFor`now?

Thx for your help!

Comment: Take a look on that discussion, maybe it would help [link](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10122)

Comment: @AmirArbabian: I already did and spend hour of work to get it to work, but it doesn't. Isn't there really no re-usable example with simple code out there?

Comment: Try [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nahgrin-virtual-scroll-table-cvxa7v), for example.

Comment: @AmirArbabian: I'm sorry my answer was wrong: I got the code getting to run (like in the example) but the problem is still that the header is NOT fixed but moving.

Comment: Lars Hagen . Hi. there, How can I contact you? I need help with cdk-virtual-scroll.

Comment: @mex I created a chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215503/mex

Comment: Thank you Lars. It's working perfect. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi. Lars. I need help with ngx-virtual scroll. How can I add a regular horizontal scrollbar for the table with ngx-virtual scroll if overflow occurs in the x-direction?

Answer (score 0):

Because I couldn't find a real working solution I wrote my own "quick & dirty" code for a fixed header. Nevertheless I hope to find a much better way in future. Perhaps the next release of Cdk will offer a solution.

What I did now is to wrote a (more or less hack) directive that clones the table from within the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` and places the cloned node before. In the next step the `visibility` of the `table thead` element is set to `collapse`.

**Usage:**

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="30" cloneThead>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            ...
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *cdkVirtualFor="let item of list">
                <td>...</td>
                ...
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

The `cloneThead` directive is pretty simple:

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[cloneThead]'
})

export class CloneDirective implements AfterViewInit{

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        let cloned = this.el.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);

        let table = cloned.querySelector("table");
            table.style.position = 'sticky';
            table.style.top = '0';
            table.style.zIndex = '100';

        this.el.nativeElement.appendChild(table);
    }
}
```

This works pretty well but has still one big issue: the clone is created after `ngAfterViewInit` which effects that the table rows of `cdkVirtualFor` are not yet created to the DOM.

This is good for the clone itself, because it doesn't yet contain any `tr` elements of the `tbody`, BUT the computed CSS styles for the correct widths for the `th` elements are also not known.

So all `th` elements need to have a CSS width attribute. Otherwise `th` widths and `td` widths can differ - which looks ugly...

Maybe somebody else has a solution to make a "real" clone, after the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`-table has been drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **updated solution**

a big problem of the previous code was that it wasn't able to dynamical calculate the widths of columns. So it was necessary to specify a with to every column.

This version fixes this issue.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[cdkFixedHeader]'
})

export class FixedHeaderDirective implements AfterViewInit{

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(){

        // get the viewport element
        let cdkViewport = this.el.nativeElement.closest("cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport");

        // check if table was already cloned
        let clonedHeader = cdkViewport.querySelectorAll('.cloned-header');

        // create a clone if not exists
        if (clonedHeader.length == 0)
        {
            let table = this.el.nativeElement.closest('table');
            let cloned = table.cloneNode(true);
                cloned.style.position = 'sticky';
                cloned.style.top = '0';
                cloned.style.zIndex = '100';

            // remove tbody with elements
            let tbody = cloned.querySelector('tbody');
            cloned.removeChild(tbody);

            // add a "helper" class
            this.renderer.addClass(cloned, "cloned-header");

            // append cloned object to viewport
            cdkViewport.appendChild(cloned);
        }       
        // 
        //  walk through all <tr> with their <td> and store the max value in an array
        //
        let width = [];
        let td = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("td");
        width = new Array(td.length).fill(0);

        td.forEach((item,index) => {
            const w = item.getBoundingClientRect().width;
            width[index] = Math.max(w, width[index]);
        })  
        // 
        //  get <th> elements and apply the max-width values
        //
        let th = cdkViewport.querySelectorAll('.cloned-header th');
        th.forEach((item,index) => {
            this.renderer.setStyle(item, "min-width", width[index] + 'px')
        })
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

The usage has been changed little bit because it was necessary for call the directive when `*cdkVirtualFor` is being processed.

```
<tr *cdkVirtualFor="let item of list" cdkFixedHeader>
    ...
</tr>
```

That's it! Not really nice but working...